# Performance impact of having a unique constraint on uniqueidentifier column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, uniqueidentifier

Creating an nonclustered index on a uniqueidentifier (i.e. real random identifier) column leads to fragmented index which can affect the performance.

On SQL Server, creating a unique constraint is [the same as](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224827(v=sql.80).aspx) creating an unique index.

**Code sample**

In this scenario, I have events coming from client applications. Under certain circumstances, these client applications can send the same event several times and I have a requirement of not saving the save event twice.

I use an `int` column for the clustered index and I keep the ID of the event in the table as a unique contraint. Here is the example:

```
CREATE TABLE EventTable
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1),
    [EventId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT UC_EventId UNIQUE (EventId),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TableId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
      [Id] ASC
    )    
)
```

**Question**

Will the unique constraint on a uniqueidentifier (i.e. the underlying index of the uniqueidentifier) affect the performance of the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1562/should-i-use-a-unique-constraint-or-a-unique-index-in-sql-server/) is a little old, but it essentially answers your question... "From a performance standpoint, UNIQUE constraints and unique indexes are effectively the same to the query optimizer and you will not see any performance benefit to using one vs the other."

Answer (score 4):

Any index, primary key or unique constraint has some performance hit.  The trade off is greater retrieval performance against slightly and often negligible write performance.

The size of the key or value to be indexed also has an affect on performance.  A UNIQUEIDENTIFIER is a 128bit value, BIGINT is 64bits, INT is 32bits.  Indexing a VARCHAR or CHAR field will reflect the size of that data type.

With a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER you can run into performance hits from something called page splitting.  A page is 8K and can hold as many records as can fit in 8K.  If you need to add a new record that falls in the middle of the full page then the existing page has to have two new pages created to hold half the original data in each page plus your new record pointer.  This is particularly painful in a clustered index as the clustered index affects the physical storage of records.

Page splitting is an inevitable part of using UNIQUEIDENTIFIER data types that is exacerbated by putting them in a clustered key.  I would recommend that you don't use a clustered key on such data types.

The benefit of UNIQUEIDENTIFIER data types (apart from uniqueness) is that their random nature prevents hot spots in data pages.

In your example you have both a INT identify field and a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER with a NewID() default.  If this is more than an example I should be curious to know why you have both?

Comment: I have updated the question to explain the need to the uniqueidentifier.

Comment: Typically the use for uniqueidentifier is used for the random write location, cited as performance increase over the size of the datatype. adding an unique index would only add a bit more overhead as the value is already unique, adding an index may help or hurt performance but this will depend on other factors, best to validate the performance both ways.

Comment: fill factor is actually a determinant of how much space is left on the page, not how full it will get before a new page is created. SQL Server will always try to fill the page. Also, fill factor does not apply to new pages that are added at the end of the index. The fill factor generally applies when the index is rebuilt.

Comment: You don't have to have a clustered index on a table.  I don't want to get into flame wars about it so again, it is worth reading Thomas Kesjer's notes on the subject.  He was often a key speaker at the SQLBits conferences and quite obsessive about performance/IO.

Comment: @DavePoole I do not think I can accept this answer as long as there is the FILLFACTOR / PAD_INDEX mentioned as an improvement. Based on DimUser's comments (and links) on this question, changing the FILLFACTOR when using uniqueidentifier can make things worse.

Comment: @Kzrystof You may be putting a too much weight on DimUser's input.

Comment: I've removed the fillfactor part of my answer. My error, sorry

Answer (score 3):

Any index has some overhead for write operations.  A index also has value for read.

If you need unique values the speed of search on of [EventId] should far exceed the cost of maintaining and index.  Without `UNIQUE` the database does not enforce uniqueness and a search for an exiting value would be a table scan.

You could reduce fragmentation with a fill of less than 100.

Default of [newsequentialid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) would also reduce fragmentation.

Comment: The problem with uniqueidentifier is that the values are often so sparse that changing fill factor could make performance worse due to dramatically increasing page reads